# How to call variables in useState object(Reactjs)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to call only one part of a useState object.

I've tried doing objectName.objectValue

```
const [form, setForm] = useState({
        firstNum: '',
        secondNum: ''
    })
    const [Sum, setSum] = useState('')
    const [isSubmitted, setSubmitted] = useState(false)
    const [Operator, setOperator] = useState(null)

    function handleOperator() {
        const f = [form.firstNum]
        const l = [form.secondNum]
        const Plus = f + l
        const Minus = f - l
        const Multiply = f * l
        const Divide = f / l
        switch (Operator) {
            case 'plus':
                return setSum(Plus), setSubmitted(false)
            case 'minus':
                return setSum(Minus), setSubmitted(false)
            case 'multiply':
                return setSum(Multiply), setSubmitted(false)
            case 'divide':
                return setSum(Divide), setSubmitted(false)
            default:
                return null
        }
    }
```

I expected their to be no errors but instead got 'firstNum is not defined'

Comment: Please edit the question, and fix formatting.

Comment: The code you've posted will not produce the error you've mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

The problem must be elsewhere, it is possible to set state to an object using the useState hook:

```js
const App = () => {
    const [form, setForm] = React.useState({firstName: 'Foo', lastName: 'Bar'})

    console.log(form, form.firstName);

    const handleChange = prop => e => setForm({
        ...form,
        [prop]: e.target.value
    })

    return (<p>
        My name is
        <br/>
        <input type="text" value={form.firstName} onChange={handleChange('firstName')}/>
        <input type="text" value={form.lastName} onChange={handleChange('lastName')}/>
    </p>)
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```